# Creating HMAC in objective C where NSData is binary valued decoded B64 and key is non-binary value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem that i can't solve. I need to perform HMAC(SHA256) in objective C where key is NSString and data is decoded B64. Found plenty of examples where data is UTFEncoded string and it worked for me as well. however, have issues in my case where decoded B64 translates to binary value that i then have to perform HMAC on.

```
-(void)copyAndPlay{
NSString *eB64 = @"fek3l4fnvn44fj43jfjk3l4ff2c33wA=";
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedStringB64 options:0];
NSString *b64E = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"Sanity:: %@", b64E);
NSString *key = @"thisisatestkey";
const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), data.bytes, data.length, cHMAC);
NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
NSLog(@"HMAC:");}
```

So, I am able to perform b64 methods with eB64 to *data and send it back to b64E and verify it is ok. To me, nothing seems wrong with below CCHmac function and *HMAC should contain proper values. However, when i compare that to Python code that works, contents of HMAC - read in lldb by 'me read "[HMAC bytes]"' don't match. However, when i use NSString that i cast to dKey in same manner like cKey, i am getting same results in both obj-c and python. I have to be doing something wrong, but not sure what.

Comment: Have you checked that the `NSData` isn't nil for `apiSecret` and `HMAC`? Without the same string or similar, we cannot reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

If the key is already NSData, why are you converting it into a string? The HMAC algorithm works on data, not strings. Assuming `testKey` is an `NSData` that represents the key:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:apiSecret options:0];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, testKey.bytes, testKey.length, data.bytes, data.length, cHMAC);
NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
```

But this isn't the "SHA256 hash of 2 values." This is an HMAC of `data` using a key, which is completely different.

Comment: Apologies, you are right. Was looking for HMAC and my example and description was desperately incomplete. Please see original post again for revised question.